# Zend Framework: Place multiple items in an 'HtmlTag'

Tags: php, zend-framework, web

I currently have this php code:

```
    // add element: Submit / Create button
    $submit = $this->createElement('submit', 'submit');
    $submit->setName('submit-form');
    $submit->setDecorators(array(array('ViewHelper'),array('Errors')));
    $this->addElement($submit);

    // add element: Reset button
    $reset = $this->createElement('reset', 'reset');
    $reset->setAttrib('class', 'minimal');
    $reset->setDecorators(array(array('ViewHelper'),array('Errors')));
    $this->addElement($reset);
```

Which basically renders this:

```
    <input type="submit" name="submitform" id="submitform" value="submitform" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="reset" />
```

And what I want to get is this.....

```
    <span>
        <input type="submit" name="submitform" id="submitform" value="submitform" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="reset" />
    </span>
```

How will I achieve this? Please and thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**addDisplayGroup**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.displaygroups) method of a Zend_Form. It will group your elements in to the structure you provide in this function.

*Display groups are a way to create virtual groupings of elements for display purposes.*

Comment: So I was able to come up with...
     $this->addDisplayGroup(array($submit, $reset), 'buttonsgroup');
     $buttonsgroup = $this->getDisplayGroup('buttonsgroup');
     $buttonsgroup->setDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'span', 'id' => 'buttonsgroup'))));

Comment: sadly, it renders nothing.. as in the entire span is empty. what am i doing wrong?:(

Comment: Firstly change `$this->addDisplayGroup(array('submitform', 'reset'), ..` you have to provide name of the elements you need to group not whole elements.